# set value for current elements and dynamically added elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I have the following code but it doesn't work

```
$("body").delegate("textarea", "ready", function () {
    $(this).val("custom value");
});
```

My intent is set that value for current elements on the dom and future textareas added dynamically to the page, is there a solution?

Comment: With your current code the ready event of body is delegated to the textboxes. However the ready event is triggered only once durin the page load, hence the current code is good as setting $(function(){$("textarea").val("custom value");})

Comment: @cybernate that works for current elements on the page, but what happend if new textareas are added dynamically? new elements won't take that value.

Comment: How are the textboxes getting added? It should be by a script. Why don't you intercept the code that creates the textbox and assign the value there? I don't think there is any event available like element added available.

Comment: Eli's answer help me to find a work around, I am doing something really general in each ajax postback so I can put my code on ajaxSucess event, thanks any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ready` is an event that occurs on the `document`, not when other elements are loaded. Unfortunately there is not a graceful solution to this either. The best suggestion I can make is that after each of your ajax requests complete, to select all `textarea`s and set their values:

```
// maybe something similar to this.
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('textarea').val('custom value');
});
```